# iOS: a single search bar that searches and filters two tables

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have an iPad app that shows two `UITableViews` (adults list on left and children list on right) side by side. I would like to implement a search bar that I can type a `name` or `mobile number` into, and it filters the results in its own table accordingly.

I found lots of tutorials that teaches the use of `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` which is not what I want. Is what I want to do achievable?

Comment: by using uisearchbar you can do that, just handle the behaviour of both the tableviews in uisearchbar delegates

Comment: done! thanks for the tip. if you want to put it as an answer I will mark it as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Firdous has mentioned in the reply, this can be achieved by handling the necessary behaviours of the `UISearchBar` delegate.

In `ViewController.h`,

`@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>`.

In `ViewController.m`,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.searchBar.delegate = self;
    ............
}
```

You can then specify any delegate method, in my case I wanted to do something everytime the text changes on the searchbar.

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    // filter the arrays for the table data based on search text.
}
```